# CookieInterceptor: Failed to get cookie from server, response code {0}, cookie authentication will not be attempted again

Tags: android, http, connection, couchdb, cloudant

facing error as unauthorized in cloudant.

> E/CookieInterceptor: Failed to get cookie from server, response code {0}, cookie authentication will not be attempted again
>   11-24 19:24:12.149 27485-27787/com.sshs.simplifiedshs E/PullStrategy: Batch 0 ended with error:
>                                                                         CouchException: error: unauthorized, reason: _reader access is required for this request, statusCode: 401, msg: Unauthorized, cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://*****_bulk_get
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.mazha.CouchClient$ExecuteResult.(CouchClient.java:139)
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.mazha.CouchClient$ExecuteResult.(CouchClient.java:89)
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.mazha.CouchClient.execute(CouchClient.java:193)
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.mazha.CouchClient.isBulkSupported(CouchClient.java:749)
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.sync.replication.CouchClientWrapper.isBulkSupported(CouchClientWrapper.java:280)
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.sync.replication.PullStrategy.run(PullStrategy.java:176)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://*****_bulk_get
>                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
>                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.http.HttpConnection.responseAsInputStream(HttpConnection.java:420)
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.mazha.CouchClient.execute(CouchClient.java:176)
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.mazha.CouchClient.isBulkSupported(CouchClient.java:749) 
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.sync.replication.CouchClientWrapper.isBulkSupported(CouchClientWrapper.java:280) 
>                                                                             at com.cloudant.sync.replication.PullStrategy.run(PullStrategy.java:176) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

event i change key and password but not solve problem. my app working prefect few hours ago but right not now able to access and facing error.

please please please help me and thank You in advance.

Comment: What version the  sync-android (CloudantSync) library are you using?

Comment: compile 'com.cloudant:cloudant-sync-datastore-android:latest.release'
  
  compile 'com.cloudant:cloudant-sync-datastore-android-encryption:latest.release'

    compile 'com.cloudant:cloudant-sync-datastore-javase:latest.release'

Comment: if you replace `latest.release` with `1.1.4` does the same error occur?

Comment: okay i am check.. replace in all of three. and thankx for help. i am waiting for you. please help to solve this issue

Comment: its working prefect 2 days before. but dnt know what happy its showing error

Comment: So it still happens with `1.1.4`?

Comment: ohhh ohhh oh.. yes its working. thank you sooooo much. last 5 hr i am check my backup and etc. and you will solve my problem within few second. you also help me before and this time also. can you explain me why its happen?

Comment: i have one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624834/how-to-sort-date-in-cloudant-query

please help if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync-android (cloudant-sync-datastore) 1.1.3 had a bug in it related to cookie authentication, version 1.1.4 fixed this, see the [change log](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/CHANGES.md) for more information.

Comment: thank you so much.. some one dead on this type of bug.lolz. thankx again.